# How can i filtering two array to get related objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array that contains categories and the other array contain Products,
in product object there's a property named `categories` it's an array of category,

So I want to push the related products into the related category,

The final Array should look like this

```
categoriesProducts = [
    {
        id: 209,
        name: 'test',
        slug: 'test',
        products: [
            {
                id: 3832,
                name: 'product name',
            },
            {
                id: 3833,
                name: 'product name 2',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 210,
        name: 'test1',
        slug: 'test1',
        products: [
            {
                id: 3833,
                name: 'product name 2',
            }
        ],
    },
];
```

so here the two arrays categories list

```
categories = [
    {
        "id": 209,
        "name": "test",
        "slug": "test",
    },
    {
        "id": 210,
        "name": "test1",
        "slug": "test1",
    },
    {
        "id": 211,
        "name": "test2",
        "slug": "test2",
    },
]
```

Product list:

```
productsList = [
    {
        id: 3832,
        name: 'product name',
        categories: [
            {
                id: 209,
                name: 'test',
                slug: 'test',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 3833,
        name: 'product name 2',
        categories: [
            {
                id: 209,
                name: 'test',
                slug: 'test',
            },
            {
                id: 210,
                name: 'test1',
                slug: 'test1',
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

Comment: Are they linked by the `name` property of the category or the `slug` property?

Comment: @Terry linked by `id` I edit the Q, my mistake :)

Comment: Your expected output doesnt seem to match the inputs. 1) Why did the first product end up in both categories 2) Why did the ids of the products change?

Comment: @Jamiec Sorry for my mistake, 1) => every product can be in one or more category

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired data output using `Array.prototype.reduce`. What you want to do is:

1. Iterate through all categories
2. For each category, go through all the products and fish out those that belong to the category you are currently iterating at
3. If we find >=1 products, then we push the category to the accumulator. This is so we don't end up with empty categories that contain no products (like the one with ID of `211`

The code can be visualized as this (note that I'm using ES6 object destructuring syntax below):

```
const output = categories.reduce((accumulatedCategories, { id, name, slug }) => {

  // Go through all products and return products that belong to current category
  const products = productsList.reduce((accumulatedProducts, product) => {
    const categoryIds = product.categories.map(category => category.id);

    if (categoryIds.includes(id)) {
      accumulatedProducts.push({
        id: product.id,
        name: product.name
      });
    }

    return accumulatedProducts;
  }, []);

  if (products.length) {
    accumulatedCategories.push({
      id,
      name,
      slug,
      products
    });
  }

  return accumulatedCategories;
}, []);
```

See proof-of-concept example below:

```js
const categories = [{
    "id": 209,
    "name": "test",
    "slug": "test",
  },
  {
    "id": 210,
    "name": "test1",
    "slug": "test1",
  },
  {
    "id": 211,
    "name": "test2",
    "slug": "test2",
  },
];

const productsList = [{
    id: 3832,
    name: 'product name',
    categories: [{
      id: 209,
      name: 'test',
      slug: 'test',
    }, ],
  },
  {
    id: 3833,
    name: 'product name 2',
    categories: [{
        id: 209,
        name: 'test',
        slug: 'test',
      },
      {
        id: 210,
        name: 'test1',
        slug: 'test1',
      },
    ],
  },
];

const output = categories.reduce((accumulatedCategories, {
  id,
  name,
  slug
}) => {

  // Go through all products and return products that belong to current category
  const products = productsList.reduce((accumulatedProducts, product) => {
    const categoryIds = product.categories.map(category => category.id);

    if (categoryIds.includes(id)) {
      accumulatedProducts.push({
        id: product.id,
        name: product.name
      });
    }

    return accumulatedProducts;
  }, []);

  if (products.length) {
    accumulatedCategories.push({
      id,
      name,
      slug,
      products
    });
  }

  return accumulatedCategories;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank You.  it's a good idea to use a reduce :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by looping over every category:

```
categories.map((category) => {

  return {
    ...category,
    products: /* ... */,
  }

});
```

All you need to fill in the blank is to *filter the array of products that have a certain `categorys.id`*:

```
categories.map((category) => {
  function check(categoryInProduct) {
    return categoryInProduct.id === category.id;
  }
  // or even just: 
  // const check = ({id}) => id === category.id;

  return {
    ...category,
    products: productsList.filter((product) => {
        return product.categories.findIndex(check) !== -1;
    }),
  }

});
```

`filter` will only return array elements where the function returns `true`.

`findIndex` will return > -1 if an array element was found that satisfies the `check`.

`check` will return true if the `id` of the array element matches `category.id`.

Comment: Thanks, It's Pretty Simple i never thought about it, OH GOD I want to learn more about JS :|

Comment: A lot of modern syntax makes this simple: `Array.prototype.findIndex`, rather than having to make a loop, `const newObject = { ...originalObject }` to copy properties by destructuring rather than `Object.assign()` or another loop. It's why I started my answer with "loop, then fill in the blank" & then the final code. If you break down your problem like that, the answer will come more easily to you.